# Javascript Solution Remove Specific Tag but leave the rest in a specific DIV

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

I have a div structure that looks like this...

```
<div class="gallery_lightview">
    <div id="lg_image">
        <a href="http://www.website.com/?iframe=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" class="lightview_main" title="TITLE HERE">
            <img class="alignnone" src="HEADER.jpg" alt="" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is remove the  tags that show up ONLY between div class "gallery_lightview" and leave the  tag. So once its all stripped out it would look like...

```
<div class="gallery_lightview">
    <div id="lg_image">
        <img class="alignnone" src="HEADER.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically making this a non clickable image. Is this possible? Its going on a Mobile site and I don't want this to be in the header. Really wanted it to be a self contained Javascript that sat above the `"the_content"` Wordpress call (which is where the `"gallery_lightview" div` code is.

I choose to not use a jQuery because, since its mobile it would add to the load. And literally the only thing the library would be doing was removing the `<a>` tag.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Comment: If you're not using JQuery, you should probably remove the tag to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like take the innerHTML of the inner element and make it the innerHTML of the grandparent. So:

```
var div = document.getElementById('lg_image');
var img = div.childNodes[0].childNodes[0];
div.innerHTML = img.innerHTML;
```

This isn't pretty, but it's lightweight and works. The more elegant option might be to pare down jQuery or find a similar, lighter-weight library.

Comment: Keep in mind that the text node(s) (linebreak+tab) may throw off the `childNodes` index.

Comment: True, but you could use getElementByTagType or whatever in that event. Presumably whoever is writing this code has some knowledge/expectation of what's going to be in the node or they wouldn't be doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS solution - I've given the target `<a>` an id of `"target"`.  You can grab the object however you wish:

HTML:

```
<div class="gallery_lightview">
    <div id="lg_image">
        <a href="foo" rel="bar" class="baz" title="TITLE HERE" id='target'>
          <img class="alignnone" src="HEADER.jpg" alt="" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
// Grab anchor object
var target = document.getElementById('target');
// Grab img object, using tagName to avoid possible text nodes
var img = target.getElementsByTagName("IMG");

// Append the image object as a direct child of the parent
target.parentNode.appendChild(img[0]);
// Remove the anchor (empty except for text nodes)
target.parentNode.removeChild(target);
```

If you wish to do this to many nodes, you can use the `getElementsByTagName()` to grab all `<a>`s, and then loop through using this process.

**EDIT**

The `appendChild` line was missing an array index `[0]`, now added.

**UPDATE**

http://www.jsfiddle.net/steve/yTcxn/ is a simplified version, thoroughly commented, and tested working on FF, IE, and Chrome.  It should do exactly what you want with a little personalization.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

// Grab anchor object
var target = document.getElementById('testing');
// Grab img object, using tagName to avoid possible text nodes
var img = target.getElementsByTagName("IMG");

// Append the image object as a direct child of the parent
target.parentNode.appendChild(img[0]);
// Remove the anchor (empty except for text nodes)
target.parentNode.removeChild(target);

</script>

Comment: Right before the Wordpress the_content call

Comment: Sounds like a timing problem? Make sure the nodes have been loaded before you try to work with them.  Otherwise, I put in a simplified version at http://www.jsfiddle.net/steve/yTcxn/ for you to work with (see my update).